# Cannot install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Disabled HyperV via GUI as above.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Then made sure via powershell via above.

Yet when running emulator-check.exe hyper-v:

```
hyper-v:
2
Hyper-V is enabled
hyper-v
```

I assume this is the issue. Virtualization is enabled. I have tried manually installing batch file (not in android studio). I have tried disabling Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform to install and that also didn't work (re-enabled after). CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics. Android Studio and the command were done with admin.

Comment: If someone else like me is getting headache while trying to downlad it manually (without android studio) here is the command: `sdkmanager --install extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this, was turning Virtualization OFF in the BIOS and then ON again. After doing this mulator-check.exe hyper-v showed hyper-v to be not installed, which is the expected output. I was then able to install the driver in Android Studio as usual.

Answer (score 0):

1st enable virtualization and hyper-v from your motherboard BIOS settings.

Then from the GUI enable the following:

1. Hyper-V
2. Virtual Machine Platform
3. Windows Hypervisor Platform

And after that restart your windows machine.

Comment: This had zero effect.